# react native: accordion list doesnt works in my device but works in the web snack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i have some issue while i try run this code in my device coz its not run but it run in the web snack..
i really dont know whats the problem there and how to fix it .
i scan the  QR code of the expo client but i dont see nothing but still see it works in the web snack as you can see .
i must try solve this problem coz its so important .
must say that my project is with react native with no expo, maybe this is the problem ? if yes so how can i fix it ?

[link for the snack](https://snack.expo.io/@bgpiggin/accordion-list)

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import AccordionListItem from './components/AccordionList/AccordionListItem';

const App = () => {
  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <AccordionListItem title={'List Item'}>
          <Text>Some body text!</Text>
        </AccordionListItem>
      </View>
  );
};
export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: '2rem',
    paddingTop: '5rem',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
});
```

**AccordionListItem.js**

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  StyleSheet,
  Animated,
  Easing,
} from 'react-native';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const AccordionListItem = ({ title, children }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const animatedController = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [bodySectionHeight, setBodySectionHeight] = useState();

  const bodyHeight = animatedController.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, bodySectionHeight],
  });

  const arrowAngle = animatedController.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['0rad', `${Math.PI}rad`],
  });

  const toggleListItem = () => {
    if (open) {
      Animated.timing(animatedController, {
        duration: 300,
        toValue: 0,
        easing: Easing.bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1),
      }).start();
    } else {
      Animated.timing(animatedController, {
        duration: 300,
        toValue: 1,
        easing: Easing.bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1),
      }).start();
    }
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => toggleListItem()}>
        <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
          <Text>{title}</Text>
          <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ rotateZ: arrowAngle }] }}>
            <MaterialIcons name="keyboard-arrow-down" size={20} color="black" />
          </Animated.View>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <Animated.View style={[styles.bodyBackground, { height: bodyHeight }]}>
        <View
          style={styles.bodyContainer}
          onLayout={event =>
            setBodySectionHeight(event.nativeEvent.layout.height)
          }>
          {children}
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    </>
  );
};
export default AccordionListItem;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bodyBackground: {
    backgroundColor: '#EFEFEF',
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  titleContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: '1rem',
    paddingLeft: '1.5rem',
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#EFEFEF',
  },
  bodyContainer: {
    padding: '1rem',
    paddingLeft: '1.5rem',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
```

Comment: what is the error message you receive?

Comment: no error..u can try to scan the QR code and see that its not run in your device.

Comment: not going try it but if it serves your purpose you can try [react-native-combobox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-combobox)

Comment: in your example its not works in the snack .. can u show me works snack ?

Comment: This is exactly what I need but I would love a code that works

Comment: ok its works but i cant see the arrow icon..i see a square with an X inside it and not the arrow that alternates from top to bottom

Comment: try running 'npm i react-native-elements'

Comment: its not help. what should i do?